# How to set data breakpoints (i.e. watchpoints) on VSCode

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am no expert in VSCode, but I saw that since version 1.38 there is the possibility to add watchpoints (a breakpoint which breaks when a given memory area is modified, a feature that is supported by many debuggers), at least for C/C++, see here https://jaxenter.com/vs-code-1-38-161797.html and here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58304. Now my version of VSCode is 1.48.2, and I still can't figure out how to do it, and I couldn't find a proper explanation either. If anyone can give an explanation on how to do it (or whether it is possible), for sure it will very beneficial for me and for the VSCode community.

Comment: Version 1.48 is not that old.  I assume you have seen this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging, and that you noted the need to install extensions: _"look for Debuggers extensions in our VS Code Marketplace or select Install Additional Debuggers in the top-level Run menu."_

Comment: the debugger support for c++ is pretty limited, you can only set line breakpoints. You can set other breakpoints manually through the debugger console

Comment: @ryyker yes, I did read that page, it mentions data breakpoints as well. I have the C/C++ extension installed.

Answer (score 6):

I personally use the `CodeLLDB` extension for C++ debugging as I use LLDB. The way I create a variable watchpoint:

- Put a regular break-point at where the variable is defined
- Upon hitting the break-point, find the variable in the `Variables` pane, right click, and choose `Break When Value Changes`

Comment: source to back this up: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58304#issuecomment-516011333

Comment: As of at least Oct23 this is enabled for gdb too.

Comment: The `Break When Value Changes` option is only available for in the Variables (local variables) menu.  Is there any way to add a data break point for a global variable?  Ideally the same `Break When Value Changes` option would be available for variables in the Watch area.