# VSCode, C++ and Data Breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use Data breakpoints in VSCode 1.53.2 to debug C++, and I can't find how to define them. I've already installed the Microsoft C++ extension, but when debugging, I don't have any contextual command on a variable in the Variables or in the Watches panel.
I've read this page in detail:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging
and I've seen the paragraph about Data Breakpoints, but I don't get why I don't have the menu to define them.

Do you know what I'm missing to activate this functionality or is there any specific debugger or extension to install to benefit of these Data breakpoints ?

Comment: Which debugger are you using? See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691261/how-to-set-data-breakpoints-i-e-watchpoints-on-vscode